# 'Circle" недоступен из-за его уровня защиты

Tags: c#

Есть такой фрагмент кода:

```
using System;
using ShapeAreaCalculation;
namespace TestMyLibs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Shape myShape = new Circle(10);
        }
    }
}
```

В проекте подключена библиотека 
с абстрактным классом Shape и дочкой Circle
Shape:

```
namespace ShapeAreaCalculation
{
    abstract class Shape
    {
        public abstract string ShapeName { get; set; }
        public abstract double ShapeArea { get; }
        public abstract bool ShapeCheck { get; }
    }
}
```

Circle:

using System;

```
namespace ShapeAreaCalculation
{
    partial class Circle:Shape
    {
        public override string ShapeName { get; set; }
        public double CircleRadius { get; set; }
        public override bool ShapeCheck
        {
            get
            {
                if (CircleRadius > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Warning! Radius must be positive!\nPlease check input parameters");
                }
            }
        }
        public override double ShapeArea
        {
            get
            {
                if (ShapeCheck)
                {
                    double circleArea = Math.PI * Math.Pow(CircleRadius, 2);
                    return Math.Round(circleArea, 4);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Warning! Radius must be positive!\nPlease check input parameters");
                }
            }   
        } 
        public Circle(string ShapeName, double CircleRadius)
        {
            this.CircleRadius = CircleRadius;
            this.ShapeName = ShapeName;
        }
        public Circle(double CircleRadius)
        {
            this.CircleRadius = CircleRadius;
            ShapeName = "NoName";

        }


    }
}
```

В общем, подключил длл, везде все паблик, почему ругается "CS0122'Circle" недоступен из-за его уровня защиты". Облазил весь гугл, не могу найти(или понять что нашел) ответ.
Заранее благодарен

Comment: Апд, после того, как написал вопрос, сразу понял в чем дело ><

Comment: элементы классов вы пометили модификаторами доступа, а сами классы почему-то нет. Пометьте классы, которые должны быть доступны из других проектов модификатором public